# parse delimited text file using split

Tags: java, spring-boot, parsing, split, csv

I'm trying to read a file and split the lines by the delimiter but the file i was given i was told was space delimited but i don't think it is. im getting a error saying 
`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` at 
`.map(val -> new ZygateEntity(val[0],val[1],val[2]))` line when i change my regex from `split("[\\t]` to `split("[\\ ]` my first row in the table is done but the other two rows are empty. below is my file format and the code im using to parse

file

```
20200321   text file 
TACL-SEC                          SECURITY      \SC1
TACL-SEC                          SECURITY      \SC2
TACL-SEC                          SECURITY      \SC2
TACL-SEC                          SECURITY      \SC2
TACL-SEC                          SECURITY      \SC2
TACL-SEC                          SECURITY      \SC2
20
```

Comment: Use `\\s+` as the regex for method `split()`.

Answer (score 0):

bounce the `.map(s -> s.split("[\\t]"))` this part more, use your ide search and try to find out what exactly separates columns, and probably your first and last line will be different than the actual data rows.

for regex you can use https://regex101.com/